# How is Avast auto-inserting a signature into my browser based email?

Tags: windows, email, browser, avast, trusted-root-certificates

I recently upgraded Avast and I just noticed it is inserting signatures into my webmail. i.e. in a browser, i type an email, see my regular signature, but when the email goes out, it appends it's own signature.
This is a known issue (ahem "feature") and I was able to turn it off.

More curiously, I don't understand how it is able to do this.
I did some quick googling everything online just talks about how to disable it, not how it works.
Can anyone help give a basic explanation? 
Does it have something to do with the trusted root certificates Avast installs?

-- update --
using chrome, no avast extension installed.

Comment: Because you have configured Avast to install an Outlook add-on.  Disable the feature and/or add-on to prevent this behavior

Comment: I specificially said: "webmail i.e in a browser...". I'm not using a thick client.

Comment: My answer is the same you likely have/had an Avast browser add-on installed

Comment: no browser add-on installed.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is, since you already solved your problem, you didn't even tell us what feature you disabled

Comment: If you were using a Avast proxy, which is likely since you had the Avast MiTM feature enabled it's possible the text was being added by that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enable checking of email for malware, Avast! (and **any** other anti-malware suite with email protection) must be able to intercept the mail *before* it gets to the browser or mail client, using the certificate you mention. This is intentionally allowing "man-in-the-middle" interception, though for a good purpose -- preventing malware from being activated.

Therefore, the AV can append a footer saying "inspected by xxxx and free of malware". You can turn this notice off from the AV suites settings and/or stop inspection of outbound messages.